# Sum editable DT column and print as textOutput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I am trying to create a text output that prints the sum of an editable DT column ('cover') in a Shiny app.  When I create the output using `output$totCov <- renderText({  paste("Total Percent Cover:", sum(filtered[, 'Cover'])) })` I get the error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".  When I try to convert 'filtered' to a data.frame, I am not able to.  I want the text output "totCover" to show the sum of the 'Cover' column as it is edited in the app.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyr)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinythemes)

testData = data.frame(sciName = c ("aPox","bPro","aMor","eCol","mDif"),
                      spColor = c("Red","White","White","Red","White"),
                      Tall = c("No","Yes","Yes","No","Yes"),
                      Tolerant = c("Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes"),
                      Cover = c(0,0,0,0,0))




ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage("SFEI Planting Palette", theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
             tabPanel("Plant Selector", fluid = TRUE,
                      titlePanel("Plant Selector"),
                      mainPanel(
                        fluidRow(
                          dataTableOutput("table"),
                        ),
                      ),
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          titlePanel("Site Characteristics"),
                          "Characteristics to Attract:",
                          fluidRow(column(5,
                                          checkboxGroupInput(inputId= "char", label = h3("Checkbox group"), 
                                                             choices = list("Tall", "Tolerant")))),
                          fluidRow(column(5,
                                          selectizeInput(inputId = "color",
                                                         label = "Select Desired Plant Colors:",
                                                         choices = unique(testData$spColor),
                                                         multiple = TRUE
                                          )),
                          ),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(),
                      )
                      
             ),
             tabPanel("Panel2", fluid = TRUE)
  ),
  mainPanel(),
  hr(),
  wellPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 11,
        align = "center", 
        h3("control panel"),
        textOutput("totCov"))))
  
)          


server <- function(input, output) {
  filtered <- reactive({
    req(input$color)
    filter(testData, spColor %in% input$color) %>%
      filter_at(input$char, any_vars(. == "Yes"))
  })
  
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
    DT::datatable(filtered()[,c("sciName", "spColor")],
                  rownames = FALSE,
                  filter = 'top',
                  editable = list(target = "column", disable = list(columns = c(0:3))),
                  extensions = 'Buttons',
                  options = list(
                    dom = 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel')
                  ),
                  class="display"
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  output$totCov <- renderText({ 
    paste("Total Percent Cover:", sum(filtered[, 'Cover']))
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: parentheses :-)

Comment: Thank you, using 'paste("Total Percent Cover:", sum(filtered()[, 'Cover']))' does sum the original column, so it returns 0, but the value does not update when I edit the column values in the table.  Any idea on how to get the text output to update with the edited values?

Answer (score 0):

If the table is editable you must implement a way to get the edits; I think a common route is via replaceData
https://thatdatatho.com/r-shiny-data-table-proxy-replace-data/